# Marker in google maps is showing in the wrong location

Tags: android, google-maps

I know the title sounds like a duplicate but I've not found a problem exactly matching mine, so bear with me. I'm passing the lat and long to my maps activity, but the marker (which is also where it zooms to) always seems to be around 100 miles away from where it should be. In a random direction too, it's not consistent on the problem at all.

My map code (passing in via an id from the database)

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

   mMap = googleMap;

   LatLng place = new LatLng(venue.getLatitude(), venue.getLongitude());
   mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place).title(venue.getName()));
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place));
   mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place, 15));
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, this is making my brain a bit wonky.

Comment: maybe try to set anchor? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float,%20float)

Comment: Double check the values of the lat/lon that you get from the venue object.  Also show how you're setting the lat/lon and how you're storing it in the Venue class.  It might be losing digits of precision.

Comment: Oh Daniel you beautiful man, I'm storing long and lat as ints instead of doubles. Knew it was going to be a silly mistake somewhere, that has to be it!